# How to fix 415 error being thrown by Swagger UI on HTTP delete

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

In Swagger UI (Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.* 1.2.0), I have an HTTP `DELETE` endpoint which supports including a payload in it. When I try to send a request to this endpoint without the payload, Swagger UI returns a `415` error, regardless of the `content-type`. If I put an empty JSON in it, it succeeds. Another thing I noticed is that when sending an empty payload, Swagger UI does not include the `content-type` header.

How do I let Swagger UI accept a `DELETE` request without a payload? (This is a hard requirement. Also, another constraint to this is I have no control on the generated swaggerdoc of the API.)

Comment: `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(o =>
    {
        o.AllowEmptyInputInBodyModelBinding = true;
    });
}`

Comment: Tried that, but isn't working. @DeepakMishra